# DHCP addressing with a switch and a router?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

I currently have a Netgear R7000 configured in my home like this.

```
Modem ---> Router ---> Wifi Devices
            \
             \- 3 Wired Devices
```

I am thinking of adding a switch between the modem and the router to allow for more LAN ports, but I do not know how to do it.

```
Modem ---> Switch ---> Router ----> Wifi Devices
             \           \
              \           \- 3 Wired Devices
                \- 16 Wired Devices
```

How would I configure everything? I need everything to be on the same local subnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your modem really is just a modem, your second schematic will not work, because the modem doesn't understand layer 3, i.e. IP. I'm assuming there is a special port on your router that you can connect the modem to.

Therefore, you would have to connect your switch behind your router (as one of the 3 wired devices) for it to work. You usually won't need to configure anything specifically with a common household switch, because it should just propagate broadcast packets (e.g. DHCP packets between the devices and the router, assuming your router is your DHCP server).

Comment: So I would need a cheap router than? A wired one. If I set the Netgear to AP mode would the 3 wired devices still connect?

Comment: You should just be able to plug your switch into one of the LAN ports on your router and connect your 16 wired devices to the switch with everything working out of the box.

Comment: The problem is that there is only one cable going to the router, and I need the switch far away in our networking box.

Comment: Then I think your possibilities are either to connect another long cable from the router back to the switch or buy a cheap router as you said, which you'd connect to the modem, the other router and the switch.

Comment: Then If I set the Netgear to AP mode would the 3 wired devices still connect?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really versed enough in Netgear equipment to answer this. If you have the hardware at hand, it might just be your best bet to try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32589/discussion-between-quynguyen2013-and-rikuxan).